# Difference between IC50 and Michaelis-Menten constant

Tags: cancer, pharmacology, theoretical-biology, enzyme-kinetics

I am new to biology, and getting to know the term IC50, I found that there is a connection between IC50 and Michaelis-Menten constant by the [Cheng-Prusoff](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0006295273901962) equation

$K_{i}=\frac{\mathrm{IC}_{50}}{1+\frac{[S]}{K_{m}}}$

where $\mathrm{K}_{\mathrm{i}}$ is the binding affinity of the inhibitor, $\mathrm{IC}_{50}$ is the functional strength of the inhibitor, [S] is fixed substrate concentration and $\mathrm{K}_{\mathrm{M}}$ is the Michaelis constant in the MM equation:

$\textrm{rate} = \frac{V_{\text{max}} [S]}{K_M + [S]}$

where $V_{\text{max}}$ is the maximum rate of reaction.

Suppose IC50 of the drug is $x$. From my understanding that means- the concentration needed to decrease cells viability by $50 \%$. Since Michaelis-Menten constant means the substrate concentration such that the reaction rate is half of maximum, it seems quite the same. What is  wrong in my view? Both seems to cause $50 \%$ of effictiveness

Comment: I have added a ref to Cheng-Prusoff.  I hope you don't mind. I was tempted to modify your opening sentence to "... Michaelis-Menten constant by the Cheng-Prusoff equation _for competitive inhibition_", but I was afraid I might change your meaning. In pharmacology, especially when dealing with receptor-agonist relationships, it is often assumed that inhibition is competitive (see [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8488569/), for example). But there is the rub with IC50 values: how do you know that the inhibition is competitive?